# Cannot upgrade packages after upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS (unmet dependencies)

Tags: upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I'm running a gaming server on a linux machine and just upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. Connection is via SSH (command lines).

Server reboots fine.

I can see that I have 310 updates which can be applied.

I used:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After the second command, I got the following error message:

```
Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies. 
grub-pc: Depends: grub-common (= 2.02-2ubuntu8.23) 
grub-pc-bin : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02-2ubuntu8.23) 
grub2-common : Depends: grub-common (= 2.02-2ubuntu8.23) 
python3-apt : Depends: libapt-inst2.0 (>= 1.6.5~) but 1.2.35 is installed
Depends: libapt-pkg5.0 (>= 1.6.5~) but 1.2.35 is installed 
systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.31) but 237-3ubuntu10.53 is installed 
udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu21.31) but 237-3ubuntu10.53 is installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Next, I tried:

```
sudo apt -f install
```

Which results in:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
required:
cgmanager fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console libcgmanager0
libcryptsetup4
libgomp1 libmpc3 libquadmath0 libsub-name-perl
linux-image-3.13.0-164-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-164-generic
python3.5 python3.5-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
apt apt-transport-https apt-utils grub-common libapt-inst2.0
libapt-pkg5.0
libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls30 libidn2-0 libpam-systemd libtasn1-6
libunistring2 networkd-dispatcher systemd udev
Suggested packages:
apt-doc aptitude | synaptic | wajig dpkg-dev multiboot-doc grub-emu
xorriso
desktop-base gnutls-bin systemd-container
The following packages will be REMOVED
systemd-shim
The following NEW packages will be installed
libidn2-0 libunistring2 networkd-dispatcher
The following packages will be upgraded:
apt apt-transport-https apt-utils grub-common libapt-inst2.0
libapt-pkg5.0
libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls30 libpam-systemd libtasn1-6 systemd
udev
12 to upgrade, 3 to newly install, 1 to remove and 366 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/9,316 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,167 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 104742 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing systemd-shim (9-1bzr4ubuntu1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service to /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd
by systemd-shim'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting
'/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service'
with  different file
'/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd',
not allowed
dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--remove):
installed systemd-shim package post-removal script subprocess
returned error exit status 2 Errors were encountered while processing:
systemd-shim
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried a variety of other commands:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I still get the same errors.

I don't really know anything about Linux (I "inherited" this server from the previous owner, who wanted to retire). As far as I can tell, I can neither upgrade these packages nor upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS right now (also tried the latter). Going to 20.04 LTS is my goal, though.

Does anyone know what I can do know? Please describe in great detail so that I can follow your steps.

Thanks!

Edit: As per guiverc's suggestions, I ran sudo apt update:

```
Hit:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:5 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-security InRelease [7,458 B]
Get:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu bionic-infra-updates InRelease [7,457 B]
Fetched 267 kB in 0s (406 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
378 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Comment: Many of your details in your pastes do **not** match the description you gave (*though some do*), as if the server was just migrated from *xenial* (16.04) to *bionic* (18.04) I would expect *bionic* packages; but a search for what you've provided in the paste shows neither *xenial* nor *bionic* (other EOL releases).  You don't *release-upgrade* using the `apt-get upgrade` command (it can't apply all upgrades anyway; `apt-get dist-upgrade` performs that function), but I would return to basics; ie. `sudo apt update` & read the output.. check what you have there first.

Comment: Thank you! I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 two or three years ago. Maybe I botched that one up...

I used sudo apt update. Will add to main post.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, a friend helped me with the dependencies. I will try to write down what we did here.

First, we tried to upgrade all dependencies manually, but after all dependency errors were resolved, the upgrade of the packages still failed on removing systemd-shim.

We solved it by removing the file related to the systemd-shim uninstallation:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service /tmp/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service

sudo rm /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service
```

Check if the file has been removed with

```
sudo ls -l /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service
```

It should say "No such file or directory".

Then we upgraded the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install systemd udev libpam-systemd libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg5.0 grub-common
```

The installation went through without any errors, but my friend said we can only know for certain if everything is okay after the next reboot. Since I already have player on right now (thought I wouldn't get this done today and turned our game process back on), I will reboot some other time. Hopefully it'll turn back on then...